# QWidget background images not appearing when parent exists

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a simple widget which uses an image as background and contains some child widgets.  When I create it without a parent (as a dialogue) everything is perfect. But if I create it as a child of some other widget, I can't see the background.

**Can I use QWidget::setPalette to set the background for a child widget?**

If not, how would you accomplish this?

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QLabel>

class Panel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Panel(QWidget *parent = 0)  QWidget(parent)
    {
        bgnd_ = new QPixmap(":/path/to/image.png");
        PaintBackground();

        QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("SomeChild",this);
    }

private:
    void PaintBackground()
    {
        QPixmap bgnd = bgnd_->scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

        QPalette palette;
        palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bgnd);
        this->setPalette(palette);
    }
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
    {
        QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
        PaintBackground();
    }

private:
    QPixmap* bgnd_;
};
```

If I create this widget as an independent object with no parent, then it will render fine.  I see the background and the child widget.  If I create this widget as a child of another widget, then I see the lowest-level child, but the background is empty.

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "panel.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        Panel* solo = new Panel();
        solo->show();

        Panel* child = new Panel(this);
    }
};
```

The above class instantiates the widget in 2 ways:  `solo` gives me a dialogue with everything looking perfect.  `child` lets me see `Panel`'s child widgets, but the background is white.

**Troubleshooting details**

I thought this could be a bug in Qt as described [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/43104/solved-possible-bug-in-qapplication-setpalette-what-to-do/6) so I tried filtering out ThemeChange events by reimplementing the following in both `Panel` and `MainWindow`.

```
bool event(QEvent *event) override
{
    if (event->type() != QEvent::ThemeChange)
    {
        return QWidget::event(event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

That didn't help.

Comment: If you want to set the background of your mainwindow, than set the palette IN the mainwindow.  Also, use "setCentralWidget(panel);"  If you only want the image appear in a child window, use paintEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of painting my background with a `QPalette` in `resizeEvent` I found that the answer was to paint it with `QPainter` in `paintEvent`.

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QLabel>

class Panel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Panel(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        bgnd_ = new QPixmap(":/path/to/image.png");

        QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("Hello",this);
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* e )
    {
        QPainter painter( this );
        painter.drawPixmap( 0, 0, bgnd_->scaled(size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));

        QWidget::paintEvent( e );
    }

private:
    QPixmap* bgnd_;
};
```